# How to structure and connect a python project (not a web application) with Django project?

Tags: python, django, jobs, job-scheduling, python-architect

I have a processing engine built in python and a driver program with several components that uses this engine to process some files.

See the pictorial representation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj79v.png).

The Engine is used for math calculations.

The Driver program has several components.

1. Scanner keeps scanning a folder to check for new files, if found makes entry into DB by calling a API.
2. Scheduler picks new entries made by scanner and schedules them for processing (makes entry into 'jobs' table in DB)
3. Executer picks entries from job table and executes them using the engine and outputs new files.

All the components run as separate python process continuously. **This is very in efficient, how can I improve this?** The use of Django is to provide a DB (so the multiple processes could communicate) and keep a record of how many files are processed.

Next came a new requirement to manually check the processed files for errors so a UI was developed for this. Also the assess to the engine was to be made API based. See the new block diagram [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XlwY.png)

Now the entire thing is a huge mess in my opinion. For start, the Django now has to serve 2 different sets of API - one for the UI and other for the driver program. If the server stops, the UI stops working and also the Driver program stops working.
Since the engine is API based there is a huge amount of data passed to it in the request. The Engine takes several minutes (3 to 4) to process the files and most of the time the request to engine get timeout. The Driver program is started separately from terminal and it fails if Django server is not running as the DB APIs are required to schedule jobs and execute the jobs.

I want to ask what is the beast way to structure such projects.

- should I keep the Engine and driver program logic inside Django? In this case how do I start the driver program?
- Should I keep both of them outside Django, in which case how do I communicate with Django such that even if the Django server is down I can still keep processing the files.

I would really appreciate any sort of improvement ideas in any of the areas.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your post accordingly

Comment: I would suggest you keep everything in your Django app. It would make things easier to manage and maintain. I did not understand why it is difficult for you to access it. You can simply access that data from a URL is you have templates in the Django or you might just exchange data using the REST API.